# Android app sometimes fails to load the last answer if there's lots of them

Tags: bug, answers, android-app

Observed in Android app v1.0.43 and earlier, on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2.

1. Visit a question with lots of answers. "Lots" could be more than half a dozen, I'm not sure how many yet. This one will do, it has 19 answers: [How can we make First Posts review actually useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234153/how-can-we-make-first-posts-review-actually-useful)
2. Switch to the answers tab. Flick all the way to the last answer quickly.
3. The content of the last answer might fail to load altogether, and stay blank. Comments will load, its score will load, everything except its content will load. Scrolling back up and down again won't make it load. You just have to leave the question and re-enter.

Practically speaking: if I see a question has new activity, I'll sometimes do this to flick to the most recent answer, which will often have a lower score than all the others.

Alternately, this *just now* happened when tapping a comment notification that was on the last answer on the list. The comment notification took me to that answer at the bottom... and loaded the content of every answer *except* that one.

Sometimes, if there's lots of answers, I notice that the bottom answer(s) — I'm not sure if multiple fail to load, or just the very last one — fail to load in this way.

Comment: I've noticed this occasionally but never figured out what makes it happen. It's not always the last answer; usually it's near the end though. (And sometimes it's multiple answers, which is really rare.) +1

Comment: I seldom to browse questions with a lot of answers on app, but it seems it's more reliable than before (after Q&A page renewal, and after fixing hardware acceleration bug, e.g. blank posts). Not repro on v1.0.83 on Formatting Sandbox with 3G connection (warning: scrolling 350+ answers can be tiring): even though the answers sometime jump up & down due to loading (lazily?), all of them were loaded in the end.