# Why is SE giving so much attention to the "be nice"-policy?

Tags: discussion, be-nice-policy, rant

Recently we have been treated to featured meta posts and blog posts about the importance of the "be nice"-policy, and how/why it should also apply to comments.

This is all fine. Educating each other about how we see their actions is surely the best way forward.

But, it seems to me the efforts of the offical SE are a bit one-sided in this regard. I like to discuss what I see as a **cause** of the untoward comments. After all, diagnosing and curing the cause is often more effective than concentrating on an isolated symptom.

A bit of personal background (explaining the [rant](/questions/tagged/rant)-tag). I served as a diamond moderator on Math.SE for 3½ years. Lately I grew frustrated with the rampant dupe/homework asking/answering. I had, of course, nailed my colors to a mast of the flagship of [the caretaker fleet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/5001846). Eventually I lost my cool, and lashed out at a few repeat offenders. After this happened a few times I decided that rage makes bad fuel for a moderator, so I quit. I think I have counted to ten since - you be the judge.

On with my main point. Many of the borderline rude/abusive comments I have seen (and handled) were in my opinion caused by the commenter's frustration. Directed either at the asker or the answerer (or...). You see, neither group of users of [types 2 or 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/5001846) pays any attention to site hygiene. Many questions were poorly researched (=the umpteenth incarnation of the same calculus or elementary number theory exercise), many were copy/pasted homework assignments. The answerers reproduced their versions of earlier junk answers, and danced along merrily. They got their 2 upvotes, the asker got their homework done. I'm sure you know the mechanism from elsewhere in the SE network. Sure, we put the question on hold, occasionally even manage to delete it. But, enough of those questions survive our wishy-washy site policies, so the incentive to keep answering them remains. The autocatalytic mechanism invites more copy/pasted homework. The word gets around...

> My thesis is that giving users **effective** tools to stop the flood of poorly researched questions (and answers to such) would go a long way towards eliminating those unpleasant comments.

Sporadic thoughts:

- It seems to me that the effect of the "be nice to noobs"-policy is to gradually throw away all [the Burning Man principles](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/23/strange-and-maddening-rules/) Joel Spolsky described as necessary. Is this now the official SE view, or is it just a side-effect of the emphasis on politeness.
- Namely, a 2-minute guided tour is not gonna cut it, if the new asker doesn't internalize the message that they are **not** entitled to instant gratification with minimum effort on their part. May be this is a generation thing? Reminiscing the days when new kids on the block were cautious, timid even, taking their time learning the local do's and do-not's.
- The caretakes-types may be more prone to [Duty Calls](https://xkcd.com/386/) than your average user. But, these people got addicted to the SE model early on. They have contributed a lot. They are deeply invested in the well being of the site, and won't let the mob destroy it. Give them effective weapons, please. I'm afraid these outbursts will continue otherwise.
- I concede that targeting the newbie askers here is not really fair, but we should double the effort to educate them. The answerers have more skin in the game, and can be reached. But downvoting answers to sub-par questions is not really a sufficient deterrent. Pity upvotes are a thing here.

I see myself (probably many caretakers feel the same way) as a seasoned art fan in a museum, say, Guggenheim. What's happening is roughly the following (yes, I have tinted spectacles):

1. While having quality time at an exhibition, I spot a hoodlum with a spray can doing their worst.
2. Not forgetting the "be nice" -policy, I ask them to stop, politely.
3. He just laughs at me. A passer-by comments on how nice the sprayed on piece of art looks. They high-five.
4. I call the museum guard, who waves a finger at them, and adds the "painter" to the list of persona non grata. But, first things first, I need to save the true piece of art. So I painstakingly clean up the mess.
5. Next week, the same thing happens. As does on weeks three through six.
6. On week seven, the same things happens again. I've had enough. I tell the next dude with the spray can in unmistakable terms what I think. After escorting the dude out the museum guard comes to me, cleaning up the mess. He then reminds me of the strict "be nice to other patrons" -policy the museum has. You see, this visitor was a noob who didn't have the time to read the instructions not to apply a spray can in the vicinity of the pieces at this exhibition.
7. On week eight. I see yet another dude wielding a spray can enter the museum. I lose it and punch him in the nose. The guard promptly escorts me out. "Sir, that person is a noob. May be they were just starting to read the instructions, and about to leave their spray can in a locker? I'm going to have to ask you to leave."

Education, I said? Can somebody educate me, please.

How can we best deal with our own (and each others) frustration?

---

Edit:

Thanks to all for participating. I realize that my analogy was not fair. It is easy to understand that most new askers are a bit confused (also overwhelmed by the site rules). I came out as targeting the noobs, when in reality my words and actions lately have been targeting *the enablers* (those who answer bad questions without first engaging with the asker) aka type-3 aka [term discontinued]. I walk away from this thread with the following:

- Ignoring the force of human nature is not very wise.
- When serving I often referred to the SE staff as *Overlords* (when mere diamond powers were insufficient to serve a need). Subconciously giving them god-like powers. Cap'n Obvious called me and told me that they, too, have limited resources, and cannot fix everything right away, and need to *prioritize*.
- We all need to compromise to coexist (but my mind is still in a place where I don't see the type 3's doing their part...).
- May be the incentive structure needs fine tuning? Incentivize dupe hunting/closing? Disincentivize dupe/LQ answering?
- Or (more radical) ABOLISH rep score altogether. Well, not altogether, but may be only post *per tag rep*! I don't know about SO, but at least in math the rep user has earned on *a relevant tag* correlates better with their ability to give quality answers rather than the overall rep. Total score is inflated by the low hanging fruits.
- I realize that the suggestion in the previous bullet also has drawbacks. May be keep the old rep score as a currency for the purposes of privileges and bounties, but get rid of the weekly leagues and such that lead to extreme gamification (I learned that in SO some of those may boost people's job prospects, and that should be taken into account).
- I don't think I should walk away from this thread. Rather I should revisit it periodically.

Comment: Comments [archived](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1209/discussion-on-question-by-jyrki-lahtonen-why-is-se-giving-so-much-attention-to-t). This is a meaty post - consider giving your thoughts room to breath in the form of an answer.

Comment: I feel your pain. You can deal with your frustration by doing something else. Put some of the time you spend playing the SE game to better use by helping out at a local charity. They will be truely grateful for your time. Randomize your password, log out and tell your mail provider to blackhole mails from stackoverflow.email. If sufficient people do this the world will be a better place. SE may even notice a downturn in answers and attempt to solve the difficult issues rather than acting like a stuck record. Pigs may grow wings too.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Maybe it's the drought here in Colorado, but... I've been thinking a lot about water lately. In our society, water is simultaneously essential and a menace, a problem to be dealt with and a treasure to be chased after.

Water doesn't care what you want. No amount of pleading or nicely-worded signs are going to convince water to wet your parched plants when it wants to tear out a gully and carry away your precious topsoil. You can dam it, drain it, redirect it, slow it... But sooner or later, water always finds its level.

One of my earliest memories involved standing out on a freezing hillside helping my father lay out contour strips. Once plowed, the water would catch in the furrows and be absorbed, providing for the young seedlings and slowing the torrent that had previously cut deep ditches into the land. It took years and a lot of work to fully implement, but it worked: the entire farm was altered to accommodate what water wanted to do... Because the alternative was letting water destroy it. And water doesn't care.

[image: Image of contour-planted fields]
<sup>contour-planted strawberry fields, [photo by Lynn Betts, USDA Natural Resources Conservation Service.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NRCSCA00009_-_California_(533)(NRCS_Photo_Gallery).jpg)</sup>

I once compared the problems of Stack Overflow to [intensive farming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow/256084#256084); perhaps I should've considered [permaculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permaculture) instead:

> - **Care for the earth**: Provision for all life systems to continue and multiply. This is the first principle, because without a healthy earth, humans cannot flourish.
> - **Care for the people**: Provision for people to access those resources necessary for their existence
> - **Setting limits to population and consumption**: By governing our own needs, we can set resources aside to further the above principles. This includes returning waste back into the system to recycle into usefulness. The third ethic is sometimes referred to as Fair Share, which reflects that each of us should take no more than what we need before we reinvest the surplus.

How might we apply these principles here?

- **Care for the site**: the software itself is the framework on which everything else is built. The forms for creating posts and comments, the tags for organizing and integrating various sub-topics within the larger field, the infrastructure for finding and exposing each element to those who need it... All must be perpetually maintained. Like a swale across a hillside, the shape of the software itself and the meta-systems built with it (tags, documentation, scope) determine the behavior of users new and old on a fundamental level.
- **Care for the people**: None of this is easy. We too easily talk about helpful people, ungrateful people, rude people... But ultimately, everyone here is a *person*, trying to work together with others on an impossibly huge, never-ending task. We get tired and need rest; we get frustrated and need encouragement; we get overwhelmed and need assistance. We're all in this together: the folks asking questions, the folks answering them, the folks moderating, and even the folks behind the curtain here at Stack Exchange, Inc. If we don't provide these necessities for one another, no one else will. The ground will go fallow.
- **Setting limits to population and consumption**: There are limits to what any resource can provide. We may not know them, but they exist and [when they are exceeded, everyone suffers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320223/what-happened-to-stack-overflow-in-2014). We may be able to expand those limits, plow new ground, but we cannot ignore them. This is why there are limits on questions, answers, even requests... [There should probably be limits on comments too.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309321/can-we-implement-temporary-automatic-comment-ban-on-x-number-of-validated-rude/309344#309344)

About 20 years ago, I started tutoring students taking computer programming classes. Invariably, their goal was to pass the class; learning the material was at best secondary to that goal - but with care, I could sometimes slow them down, help them come away with more than just a passing grade. When I joined Stack Overflow, it was in the hope of building something that would provide, for roughly the same labor, this sort of involuntary education for *more* than a single student. I've seen an awful lot of new students over the years, and no doubt there will continue to be new students long after I'm gone. Like drops of rain hitting the ground, they follow the path of least resistance toward their level, taking with them what they can but always, inexorably, followed by more. We can work with them, strive to build a sustainable culture... Or watch this all be washed away.

Comment: Wow. Just... Thanks for sharing.

Comment: So, what is being worked on that will better allow the separation of the poisonous waters that will destroy our crops from the good waters? Or at least, without so much effort on the part of the farmers?

Comment: This water metaphor breaks down *really* fast, @Nicol... So I'll avoid going off on another rant about the shortsighted wastewater systems here in Colorado. The long-overdue ask form redesign is a method of slowing down new users, giving them time to read the guidance and maybe even their own question before posting. Meanwhile, we're looking at [putting more tools in the hands of topic experts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts). There are also a few ongoing tests aimed at improving the accuracy of search.

Comment: A few comments: 1) the idea of letting tag experts handle VLQ flags is interesting. I realize that getting that in Math.SE in addition to SO is in the distant future at best, but I already foresee the potential problem: I have seen tag gold badge holders getting into dupehammer wars, and also just undoing dupe closures. Cucumbers/type-3s often earn tag badges, you see :-/

Comment: Accuracy of search results is a major problem at Math.SE. MathJax/LaTeX. Google and friends cannot grok it. A concerned citizen coded [a useful approximation](https://approach0.xyz/search/), but it has shortcomings in its pattern matching (work in progress...). If the "usual" search were as good as the one at work when asking, things would be better.

Comment: Yeah, there's a tragedy of the commons thing that happens here (as with any shared resource), @JyrkiLahtonen - there's deep disagreements over how the site should be used, and each person's attempt to use it as they please risks spoiling others' efforts. A big part of solving that comes from recognizing that these sites *are* a shared resource, and working from that toward some sort of compromise as to how the site should be used, what goals are being worked toward, etc. "Care for the people" - we have to recognize each others' concerns and work to alleviate them or this all falls apart.

Comment: Search is a hard problem, @JyrkiLahtonen; something that *might* help a bit on math is better marking of duplicates... but of course, that's hobbled by lackluster search too.

Comment: When a search for a duplicate in math only depends on finding that TeX-snippet [approach0 actually works well](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2838956/11619). AT least sometimes. The one thing I cannot "forgive" is high rep users not bothering. Which brings me back to rereading your advice. :-/

Comment: Accepting this for giving the most food for thought. Possibly also offering something we may be able to turn into a solution. Planniing an intricate initiative for my home site... not holding my breath though (other things on my plate right now).

Comment: "We can work with them, strive to build a sustainable culture... Or watch this all be washed away."  Prescient.

Answer (score 65):

I've been trying to do some self-reflection lately and figure out why there's so much drama going on right now. (In truth, the drama isn't new. We've had these sorts of discussions nearly as long as Stack Overflow has existed.) Recently, a friend of mine, who is a psychologist by trade, told me about the [Karpman drama triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karpman_drama_triangle):

[image: Dreaded Drama Triangle]

I bring it up because there are very obvious links between this model and [Mysticial's model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/1438)<sup>*</sup> of personas on the site.The drama triangle is backed up by years of research and has been used to diagnose practical interpersonal problems. Since it's a more general model, there are also generalized solutions to break out of it. So, I think it's useful to think about where we all fit in the drama.

It might be easiest to think of the model in a family situation. Imagine a father who has high standards for his children and always makes them do extra chores (persecutor). His wife disagrees with his methods and helps out their children when her husband is not paying attention (rescuer). The children learn to depend on their mother to protect them from their father (victims). In extreme situations, this could be abusive. But let's think of a family that's fairly well adjusted. The father's demands are ordinary things like picking up after yourself and doing the dishes.

It's pretty clear that **I and other employees of Stack Overflow see ourselves primarily as rescuers**. Judging from your analogy, I'd guess that's where you put yourself too. It's generally the role that's seen as the most noble and desirable to be in. But it's important to be aware that *playing any role in the drama means you are adding to the drama*.

The rescuer believes they are making the situation better, but can be enabling the victim's helplessness. Rescuers tend to be disappointed when the victim fails to appreciate their help. Rescuers fail to address the problem created by the persecutor, who often feels like *they are* the victim in this situation. (In fact, the roles are fluid though one is usually primary.) Often rescuers are avoiding dealing with their own struggles by focusing on other people's problems.

I've talked about this idea with the rest of the community team, but it's mostly my personal way of thinking about drama on the network. Many people at the company are sensitive to the people who seem most in distress. Whether consciously or not, we tend to think of new users, first-time askers and non-users as victims of a small number of active users. **There's a very real risk the company is [enabling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enabling) negative behavior.** It sounds like this is *exactly your concern*.

Over the years, we've attempted to [protect the site from a flood of questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438). To quote myself:

> Ultimately, we have millions of people visiting the site. While there are many prompts, blocks and limits slowing down questions, the small percentage of visitors who make it through turns out to be a large absolute number. For better or worse, the barriers to asking mean that the most determined (or, perhaps, desperate) users actually post.

Notice that **efforts to block askers are seen as persecution by people outside of the community**. And it's hard to disagree with that assessment. Along with the spam and unresearched questions, we are certainly discouraging some legitimate questions too. Meanwhile, within the community demanding askers can also be persecutors. I've personally been berated by people who are blocked from asking. They feel it's their right to post on the site. In other words, both new users and seasoned veterans can be victims. (And it's possible we're enabling them both.)

With the [mentoring experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project) and the ["Ask a question" wizard prototype](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype), we are thinking of new ways to coach askers. Similarly, the work we are doing with "be nice" is an attempt to coach answerers who are frustrated with bad questions. We believe we need to tackle both ends of the issue if we hope to make a difference. In these examples, we're not enabling, but taking the [role of coach](http://powerofted.com/coach/) to help users succeed.

Stack Overflow has programmer culture in our DNA. As a profession, we tend to think there are technical solutions to every problem. In the weeks, months and years to come, the company is going to imply or outright say we have solutions to problems on the sites. **Don't believe us.** At best we can provide the tools users need to address social problems and change the systems behind the site to nudge people in the right direction.

We've said for a long time our sites are ["built and run *by you*"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What that means is you have agency to create content and, as you gain reputation, curate other people's content. If you are feeling helpless in the face of vandals (or vampires or other villains), the system isn't working for you. If a new user feels they can't ask a question safely, the system isn't working for them either.

---

Footnote:

<sup>*</sup> That post uses phrases for users which [we no longer use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore).

Comment: I'm about to go on vacation, but I didn't want to leave some of these thoughts unsaid. Please forgive me if they rub you the wrong way. When I come back from some time off, I'll revisit this to see if I was speaking from an honest place or if a mental break has changed my mind.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Jon. Studying the responses here does give me some perpective. I haven't really settled to a "new" role, and am still processing all that happened. May be I should have counted to twenty before posting? Anyway, venting frustration (or blowing off some esteem, as I used to call it) in itself made me feel a bit better.

Comment: I'm glad to have had the opportunity to write this, @JyrkiLahtonen. We at the company really do take on the role of rescuers promising to solve all your problems. (See Docs, Jobs, Teams, etc.) Even if we could, it's not a healthy place for us.

Comment: your figure lacks the fourth angle. Using your analogy the problem with these these "victim kids" is they beat other kids in the street. Returning back to Stack Overflow situation, askers flooding site with inappropriate questions make it hard to use for folks like me, for those who rely on SO help in searching for solutions to their programming problems. [Quoting self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness/366783#comment579915_366783), "I don't want my search results polluted with useless solutions to homework dumps..."

Comment: Thanks for sharing your very valuable insight. Given that Tim Post and Shog are most prominent, it is easy to forget that there is an invisible group of SE who has experiences which I and other users here don't see. It's easy to conflate opinions of the most prominent employees here with the team of Stackexchange.

Comment: This one doesn't include the content. Granted, the content is not a person, but it is the most valuable asset everyone here has.

Comment: @Braiam: I guess I don't see how content can create drama on it's own. Surely it is _people_ who create, edit, vote on and delete content as I say in the final paragraph. If you look at the [most valuable content we share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=MostVotes) there is _very little drama surrounding it_. Instead, the drama comes from the millions of minor questions that aren't seen by more than a hundred people. Unless someone answers and edits these questions (which sometimes happens) they usually matter only to the asker. So, you know, it's a puzzle.

Comment: @gnat: I'm curious how often this happens to you. Personally I have more problems with decent questions that solve other, but closely related, problems than I do with wildly off topic and useless answers. I can't think of a time Google  (or our internal search for that matter) showed me an answer that was utterly useless rather than just unhelpful to me at that particular time. Maybe I'm lucky? Next time you run into the problem, maybe drop a comment with your search terms so we can diagnose the issue together.

Comment: well Jon it's not bad really, at least not yet. :) My main point was to remind that DDT diagram misses one group of people (which I happen to belong to when coding). After that I just tried to match this missing group into your analogy with parents and children

Answer (score 27):

Enforcing the "Be Nice" policy is something that is actually possible. Getting people to stop posting bad questions is far, far more difficult. Of course solving one of the root causes would be a great thing, but that's not always possible. There are many real world problems that could be simply solved by creating world peace, getting people to refrain from asking bad questions is probably only marginally less difficult than that.

There is also a significant part of "Be Nice" issues that aren't directly connected to quality issues. The perception that SE is a hostile place is also a barrier to recruiting new, good users. Users that just want to dump their homework probably care much less about hostility than user that actually want to participate.

Comment: "*There is also a significant part of "Be Nice" issues that aren't directly connected to quality issues.*" I don't buy that there is a *significant* number of these issues. Problems on non-terrible questions generally arise because of a technical/personal argument between people about a question/answer. But this doesn't happen *nearly* as often as bad questions provoking bad comments. And if the powers that be can create an AI that can find "not nice" comments, why can't they train an AI to find "not good" questions?

Comment: @NicolBolas Not all sites are about technical questions, there are many other potential sources of conflict. And I suspect that some kind of machine learning approach to detecting problematic questions is something SE will do at some point, ideally also for detecting duplicates and pointing users towards them early.

Comment: ..and everything is the fault of SO curators, who must therefore spend more time framing comments and answers in an ill-defined 'welcoming, nice' fashion and less time using their vast breadth of experience in their field to handle good questions:(

Comment: 'Users that just want to dump their homework probably care much less about hostility' oh, I agree with that. They do, however care that 'hostile' or whatever, comments appear in place of an answer.  That is unforgiveable, and so they will lash out in any way they can.

Comment: I'm still undecided whether I agree or disagree with your post. I realize that my post came out strongly as targeting the noobs. Yet, my "wrath" is mostly directed at the "type 3"s or, more generally, *the enablers of bad questions*. I agree about the difficulty of stopping bad questions. But, answers to bad questions are easy to stop. Just implement a network wide policy that all answers to closed questions are deleted by the moderators. True, that won't stop some people, but those driven by reputation would soon figure out the futility of answering bad questions, restoring relative peace.

Answer (score 25):

You're conflating art vandals with users that simply have a question to ask and have difficulty navigating our (admittedly) complicated system. Art vandals are intentionally defacing things that they know others value, nervous programmers are just trying to get their jobs done.

I'm going to answer the parts of your post that don't depend on that comparison, because I just can't answer to it *while* validating certain parts of your post that I agree with. But let me toss this out:

- New users aren't art vandals, or some kind of malignancy. We're taking pretty broad strides into improving the new user experience through [a new guided way to ask questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype?cb=1), dedicating an entire team to make product improvements to help new users avoid pitfalls, and yes - admitting that our culture isn't very welcoming and taking steps to fix that.
- Math SE is pale in comparison to what we're observing on Stack Overflow. While math has some fairly complicated issues that are hardly intrinsic, it's simply in a very different place.
- We're ramping up support for, and [communication with](https://stackmod.blog) our community moderators. That's something we've never done consistently enough and I'm determined to fix it.
- Did you miss the part where I mentioned that condescension and snark [create a rather bleak self-fulfilling prophecy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311504/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-or-discourage-a-second-question)?

Finally, that we're focusing on areas where we *can* make immediate headway is in no way some kind of resignation from the others. How we prioritize depends on a vast number of things, not all of them are public (like the chronic valid email complaints of people saying awful things, among other things). We fully know that we need to do more than just influence social change in order to make things better.

But please - examine what led you to compare new users to art vandals *because it's a very common bias*. I once explained the conflict as an army of giants stepping on a heavily guarded castle and thereby threatening the very existence of the realm, and here's a *great* image to illustrate that:

[image: That's a castle, alright.]

You can totally tell that's a castle that's vital to our survival, right?

Being nicer is never a *bad* thing, and nothing is ever going to come at the *expense* of what everyone should be doing anyway. And what we're asking isn't new, we're just enforcing it, and clarifying it where needed.

---

<sub>Image credit: [BookartXD on Deviant Art](https://www.deviantart.com/bookartxd/art/If-Annabeth-Chase-made-a-pillow-fort-497026569)</sub>

Comment: Analogies often don't hold up, but now I'm curious about this story.  Care to link it?

Comment: "*You're conflating art vandals with users that simply have a question to ask and have difficulty navigating our (admittedly) complicated system.*" This phrasing ignores whether such users care about navigating our system. I submit that the people behind the torrent of low-quality questions on SO *do not care* about our system; they just want help. They aren't interested in using SO in a way that helps create a quality database; they want help. This flood creates negativity, because it is an affront to those of us who are invested in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Or to put it another way, the difference between "art vandals" and "new users misbehaving" is *irrelevant*. They both cause the same damage, and both of them must be stopped to allow SO to continue to succeed.

Comment: @NicolBolas a vandal with a can of spray paint and a clumsy person who's about to back into a display of Ming vases both do harm to the art, but their *intentions* are clearly different and that matters.  You've got to stop both of them, but treating the klutz like a vandal isn't ok.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: "*but their intentions are clearly different and that matters*" It doesn't matter to the janitorial staff who have to clean up after them, does it?

Comment: @NicolBolas I said you need to stop both of them.  One of them you want to punish; the other you want to teach.  I am assuming in this metaphor that the art museum wants to continue displaying its holdings to most of the public, saving the "you are no longer welcome here" treatment for the vandals and the unteachable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Appreciated. Perspective is what I really wanted to get here, and this contributes just that. Getting late here, more tomorrow.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: "*One of them you want to punish; the other you want to teach.*" Taking the time to "teach" someone takes time and effort *away* from those who themselves take the time and effort to ask a good question the first time. See, the problem is that you see this as personal. To you, it's about what we do to the person. To me, it's about what we do to the *questions*. The person is irrelevant; only the content matters. And if the content is low quality, for whatever reason, it *must be expurgated*. If having their content stopped or downvoted harms the person... I can live with that.

Comment: A good question dosen't need much time to take the effort to reward. Post a great answer, or even upvote. Heck, I've sometimes even put a bounty on someone else's question because I found it added to my knowledge. And No one's holding a gun to your help and asking you to engage anyone. This seems to be a bit of an extreme view.

Comment: **New users aren't art vandals, or some kind of malignancy.** Sigh, there is no filter for new users. 70% of all new users are more or less normal, 15% are exemplary users and the **remaining 15% are bad in many ways, not only as "art vandal": malicious, problematic or simply psychically draining.** There is a reason we have the "Be Nice" rule. The problem is that few problem users can make a site intolerable for regulars and other visitors, so Jyrki tries to point out that you should not only welcome new users, but retain old users *and he wants a solution, not just reaffirmations.*

Comment: I remain skeptical that SE can put any sort of appreciable dent into the asymmetry of effort problem that causes people to become rude when they otherwise wouldn't be. Cause and effect seem to suggest that prolific users that get their snark on do so because they've seen the same misbehavior too often. I don't think software can substantially change human nature, but maybe y'all will pull it off.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think we're talking about different things here. The art vandal isn't the same as a confused new user, no. But a lot of poor question askers aren't confused users. They're users that literally do not care about getting anything beyond their answer. The number of times I've seen someone post a terrible question and then abuse the people *actually trying to help them* is.. quite large. Especially on sites like SO/SU/AU. These people *don't* care. No one has a problem with the person who just needs a little help with the rules.

Comment: cc @NicolBolas --^

Comment: Frankly I'm very upset at SE and a large chunk of the community who, when people complain about the very real help vampires (oh no! I used an evil word!) exclaim "what! No, these are just poor users who need a little help with the system", completely ignoring the fact that the person was just abused by said "poor user" for exactly that. Trying to provide that "little help". This, of course, doesn't help this person's attitude towards these new users, nor the people ignoring the problem. Now multiply this by a few years.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: "*completely ignoring the fact that the person was just abused by said "poor user" for exactly that*" Can you provide an example where such cases have been "completely ignored"? Where you've flagged such comments and nothing at all was done? Where people claimed that *that particular person's conduct* was perfectly fine? Because I don't see *anyone* saying anything of the sort. Rudeness from new users is handled exactly like rudeness from long-time users: the comments are removed when properly flagged.

Comment: @NicolBolas My point is not the rudeness is rude. It is handled well. My point is the user demonstrates that they have no interest in being constructive members of the community or putting effort into a quality question. *This* is ignored. The rudeness is almost always cleaned up, as it should be.  And that's what happened here too. Instead of talking about the actual vandals that are described in this question, both Tim and Monica ignore these and shift the discussion (which is technically a straw man, I guess?) to "users that just need help navigating". Not at all what the OP described.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: "*My point is the user demonstrates that they have no interest in being constructive members of the community or putting effort into a quality question. This is ignored.*" It's not clear what not "ignoring" this would look like to you. That is, what do you *want* to happen? Do you want a rule where new users are instantly IP banned from the site forever for being rude to a higher-rep user? What kind of sanctions do you want, and under what circumstances would they get applied? How can we tell when someone "doesn't care" vs. when someone is just frustrated?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: Also, what is the point of improving the ask question page with a guided tour if not to encourage users to "put effort into a quality question?" If such users continue to ask poor questions, we can deal with them. But if it raises the overall quality of questions that get asked, I see that as a win for this problem. So what is being ignored?

Comment: I'm probably taking your analogy a bit too literally (given that my analogy was misguided), but are you implying that "defenders of quality content" are defending a cushion fort? I haven't participated in other Q&A platforms (since the math usenet group was overrun by crankpots), but I thought that quality and expertise is SE's shtick, separating it from Yahoo Answers and such. Admittedly in the eyes of a professional math guy "quality and expertise" mean something different than they do to a calculus help seeker.

Answer (score 19):

> How can we best deal with our own (and each others) frustration?

Before I answer that question, lets dive into some anecdotes and metaphors, seems proper. Lets start first with two anecdotes, one very recent and another somewhat old and then a study on the cost of stuff.

I was attending to a beginners course for R, in which the facilitator at the end recommended some books and tools to help yourself. One of those tools was "Stackoverflow", which was described as "super helpful". I was flabbergasted. Stack Overflow being helpful? In that same breath, while explaining the usefulness of SO in a quickie, mentioned two things:

- "you can ask questions", to which I almost screamed "NO!" and
- "most likely the answer is already there, so you just have to search for it" ...!? Wait, what?

So, there you have it. SO is not only helpful to beginners, you are recommended to ask questions in it, but not without searching before. Why couldn't people introduce Stack Overflow that way to everyone? Also, although is not the first time I heard about SO in my immediate surroundings, is the diametrical opposite of the anecdotes that many people share about the site.

The other anecdote is about my first question on SO. Is not deleted, and if you see the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6301700/1), other than the first line, there isn't much to improve. I kind of meet all the criteria of [Jon Skeet question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and I was trying to mixing three libraries, a framework (which isn't shown) for a small project after less than 12 hours of reading some python documentation. Granted, is not an stellar question, but it got 2 upvotes, no downvotes and no unnice comment (as far I remember).

There's a common theme on both anecdotes: they do the "right" thing that most as veterans SE members have present. I like to think that both individuals involved did for a single reason: respect for the <s>art</s> site and its dwellers.

And this respect, usually comes as a cost for the user, since they are more invested into the goods it has value, since they know [it's not free](https://www.ft.com/content/7cf80be4-2ec8-11de-b7d3-00144feabdc0):

> Another important element of the distribution campaign is ensuring they are used properly. This means **discouraging people from using them** as fishing nets or cutting them into bath sponges, for example.
>
> Distributing the nets without charge can exacerbate this problem. "In sub-Saharan Africa, **there’s a tendency to look at products that are provided free as being of little or no value,**” says Mr Yeboah. “And charging some money is also a mechanism to ensure that one can sustain the supplies – because the donors are not going to continue providing them forever."

For the new user, there's no cost to interact with our sites paid upfront. Usually, when something is free of cost (not necessarily monetary) the value assigned by the users is too low, and the good or service end up being squandered by the users they are supposed to work in their own benefit. And we all know that adding value to the corpus, is not without cost. This asymmetry in costs makes the ones that actually pay frustrated, because their investment isn't being respected and used *without care*.

So, like in your analogy, informing them before entering that there's a cost and that they should respect the museum and the pieces exposed by following the guidance, would work towards actually improving the situation. Using just niceness is difficult, because most people associate it with pleasantries. Now, **respect** is more concise among cultures. For that I propose that we replace the "be nice" with "be respectful".

Be respectful of your fellow humans and [dog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135565/journeyman-geek).
Be respectful of the content of the site and maintain it.
Be respectful of the people answering and asking questions.
Be respectful of the site guidance, as that's the only thing preventing us from eating one another.

Comment: +1 for the dog reference :)

Comment: Your mosquito nets link got me thinking about the dangers of paternalism in these discussions; there's a nasty tendency for otherwise well-intentioned folks to look at the problems faced by [Africans|new users] and... start treating them like children, incapable of handling responsibility or making decisions for themselves. Something to watch out for!

Comment: @Shog9 the people on that link were all humans. Their behavior is as humans act with the proper (dis)incentives. What we need to do is to exploit the human behavior to achieve the desired results, giving the correct incentives. The purpose of that link is to illustrate how people could act against themselves, even when they are being rational. Watch out for the prisoner dilemma, which is frustratingly frequent in the real world.

Comment: Great to mention the dogs, but this post needs more horse - in the spirit of cowbell.

Comment: Free nets: I once belonged to a revolutionary Socialist organization (!). We produced educational pamphlets. But we didn't give them away free, even though buying  and selling was fundamentally against our objective. Because people will take free pamphlets... and put them in the bin unread. We wanted people to read them. So we charged a nominal price (only a few pence).

Answer (score 13):

I agree with most of the post, and know intimately the frustration you are speaking about. Still, I will write a partial answer (by no means a full one!) which you won't like.

One of the necessary conditions for dealing with this kind of frustration is empathy for the noob. Your question, which is carefully written to be very constructive despite the strong emotions behind it, still shows a bias in the way you are framing the situation. You compare the noob to a vandal who deliberately destroys a work of art.

I would suggest a reframing. Imagine that the noobs belong to a tribe which grew up in the jungle and never had contact with civilization. And you are not in a museum, but in a garden. Your jungle visitors always take the shortest path instead of staying on the paved roads, pick the prized apples from the trees and spit out the seeds on the benches. They don't do it because they want to destroy the garden, but because they don't even start to realize the concept of somebody planting a garden and keeping it in a certain state.

This reframing might clash with some notions you might have ("They are the ones destroying everything, and now I have to take their side!") but seriously, adopting this attitude reduces your own frustration, making your own day better. And it elegantly interrupts the scenario in which you are escorted out for punching somebody.

This is to be seen in addition to, and not as a replacement, to other efforts directed at reducing the damaging influence that clueless noobs have on the sites and their regulars.

Comment: And when our jungle visitors enter our garden, they should try to learn the rules, just like they would in the tribe they grew up in.  "This is the way I'm used to" is an excuse for laziness, and disrespects the gardeners keeping the place looking good for all visitors.

Comment: @fbueckert well, by the same argument "this is the way I'm used to" could be applied to the people who are used to being snarky and condescending. Being welcoming and kind benefits the entire site, not only the "noobs". How can they know they're disrespecting a gardener they don't know exists?

Comment: @Catija And we see a lot of training going on for the gardeners, and not much at all for our visitors.  Gardeners seem to be trying, but are being, and have been, ignored when they voice their concerns.  If you don't want your gardeners to be snarky, then maybe you need to install a gatekeeper that cleans up your visitors before releasing them into the garden.

Comment: @fbueckert The training for the new users requires UX changes. New users won't read meta. UX takes more time and requires developers. Writing meta posts and updating the Code of Conduct takes time but no developers. They *are* working on both halves of the equation, though. They are working on ways to educate new users in how to write better questions but being kinder to people everywhere on the network is still important and if it's faster to implement, that's OK... but I don't think it's accurate to say that they are ignoring the gardeners' concerns.

Comment: @fbueckert you bring up one of the most difficult things in community building (and highly relevant too). It is indeed important that the new people learn the basic rules in our community. And teaching and mentoring new people has its own rewards, especially in seeing the mentees get better. The difficult part here is that they do learn (slowly), but every day, there are fresh ones. So the regulars are barraged with a constant stream of noob behavior, and that's where their frustratioon comes from. Any solution has to acknowledge the need to deal with those who have not yet learned anything.

Comment: @rumtscho I've always been a huge proponent of quality.  And I do feel we can be more welcoming.  But that welcoming **has** to be a two way street.  We are a community, and new users **must** try to adapt to us.  In return, we try to guide users towards how to do so.  I see lots of attempted guidance.  I see almost no new users trying to adapt.  They are basically unicorns.  I agree this is a problem, and needs to be worked on.  I agree we can always do more.  I disagree with the current thrust, as I feel we're fixing symptoms, not the problem.

Comment: @Catija I'd *really* like to see what SE has done to help curators keep the site clean.  Because we're into, what, the third Summer of Love attempt, with the attendant backlash, and I can't seem to recall any changes SE's made to help us with that task.  So, yes, I do feel like we're being ignored.

Comment: @fbueckert that's where the [question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype) comes in. It's in early stages but the specific goal is to help users ask more complete questions (on SO). It's a form of just-in-time help. It may not be a panacea but it's absolutely designed to improve question quality and take a load off the shoulders of the curators. Such a wizard could then be adapted to other sites that have similar issues. If it's well-designed, I would hope that fine tuning it for other sites should be relatively easy.

Comment: @rumtscho: "*Any solution has to acknowledge the need to deal with those who have not yet learned anything.*" Does it? Why? Can't we just stop them from asking bad questions to begin with? We don't *have* to deal with people who can't follow the rules.

Comment: @NicolBolas i mean.. not letting them in would be one way of "deal[ing] with those who have not yet learned anything". We already put them into a quite difficult to get out of hole when they don't listen, but we need to find a way to get the point across sooner. Banning people only after they've made a mess of things doesn't help.

Comment: @NicolBolas How do you propose to stop people from asking *only* bad questions? I'm sure that the devs would love to hear a great solution to that... heck, I would, too.

Comment: @Catija So we've made one small step in three years, while every year, we have another iteration on how we have to help new users.  I'm sorry, and call me cynical, but I don't see that as enough.  My perception is that new users is more important to SE than giving us curators effective tools to keep it clean.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree. I wonder what happened. Spending time lurking and getting to know a community by watching it before posting was once part of net culture (looking back at newsgroups, newsletters etc). It was expected of new users to do their part and adapt.

Comment: @fbueckert Well, I think that there's a lot more complexity going on than just that. In a comment on the question you talk about the "quest to Get Bigger". Perhaps if you reframe that as a "quest to Be Solvent"? SO is a company. They have staff who need to be paid... and they laid off a good number of them six months ago because they needed to redirect the way the company works. They tried some things that didn't work and now (from what I understand) things are stable and they're growing... and focusing on Q&A. I appreciate that and am really looking forward to improvements.

Comment: @Catija: "*How do you propose to stop people from asking only bad questions?*" The same way the blog post proposes to stop people from making "not nice" comments: use a machine learning algorithm to figure out what "bad questions" are and cull them when the user tries to ask them.

Comment: @Catija And that brings up a good point; we don't get paid to put up with the abuse.  They do.  Are they willing to shoulder the burdens we currently have?  If not, then give us effective tools to do so.  Criticizing us and how we currently do it is shooting the messenger instead of solving the problem.  And this criticism *keeps happening*.  I'm not the only one frustrated at SE for expecting us to maintain standards, and then yelling at us when we do so.

Comment: @NicolBolas OK. Is there any indication that they're *not* doing that? I'm guessing that the question wizard is a *much* simpler thing to implement than building a ML system and might take a lot of the load off, sooner... that doesn't mean they're not considering something like that. :)

Comment: @Catija: "*Is there any indication that they're not doing that?*" That's not how evidence works. They've *said* they're doing it for comments. They haven't said they're even considering it for questions. That tells you where the focus is.

Comment: @fbueckert Tim's post from a couple of days ago specifically says that it's not about casting blame... and I share that. It's a really tough struggle to see bad content on a site you love day after day after day... and I completely understand getting frustrated by that. But that doesn't mean it's OK to take out that frustration in public and make the site look inhospitable.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think you misunderstood my comment. I was merely pointing out that every day, there will be a fresh crop of people who try to post a question which is bad by our standards, and this will happen independently of how many of yesterday's crop we have managed to educate. I am all for circumventing the actual posting of bad questions, if we can find a solution for that. My point was that we shouldn't assume that successful education of yesterday's noobs will lead to a state of "no new clueless questioons".

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, you're only looking at it from the point of view of catching the "regulars". Such a comment tool would *also* catch new users who respond in very negative ways to requests to improve their questions. It's not a one-sided tool and tons of people complain about users who overreact to requests for clarification or more info in their questions. Both are important to consider.

Comment: @Catija: "*Such a comment tool would also catch new users who respond in very negative ways to requests to improve their questions.*" Yes, it will stop them. But it doesn't matter. Such comments don't hurt long-time users; we've seen it and are clearly willing to tolerate it. And sanctions handed down to new users don't matter, since they can just make a new burner account and ask again; they have no investment in their current account. So such sanctions will affect long-time users more than new ones.

Comment: @Catija I don't buy the no blame part; Jay's blog post makes it very clear where he believes the problem lies, and platitudes about not blaming anyone ring false.  Nick's subsequent post just crystallizes where some employees think the problem is.  I agree that we can try harder.  I agree we shouldn't take it out on new users.  But I see lots being done to help new users, and vanishingly little to help curators.  So if SE wants us to be more welcoming, give us some more tools to actually *deal* with the problem, instead of just telling us we're doing it wrong.

Comment: I do concede that your analogy is better than mine in many ways. Not ideal, but I came here to get more perspective, and this serves in that role. Your garden analogy lacks the "type three users". They might be people organizing raids to "my" garden, or... :-)

Answer (score 12):

I agree with pretty much all of the points in your question. I think "be nice" is an odd topic at the moment, and there seems to be a lot of debate around what "be nice" even means.

It should be a general rule to be nice, but a lot of focus seems to be on comments for some reason, as if they're the problem. But it's not the case IMO:

- **Comments** should "be nice" and explain the rules and requirements of this site in a more welcoming way rather than short and blunt. This may make "some" people feel welcomed and more likely to improve their question/answer.
- **Question** askers should "be nice" and recognise their question is site content which can be bad and thus harmful to the site in various ways. Questions produce much work and resource usage, by bringing about the need for edits, comments, votes, flags, and answers. This is a lot of power, and with it comes great responsibility.
- **New users** should "be nice" as they're new to a site, and should take some time to learn its ways. E.g. when someone informs them their question has an issue, they should look to fix it. They should be nice and not want to come to a new site and expect everything to be their way, on a site that's been here for many years with specific ways. Once a new user posts their question there is no "us and them" they're entirely part of the "us", and should care about the site and the quality of that question.
- **Answerers** should "be nice" and recognise that answering poor questions may well give that one person information they wanted, but the site repeatedly makes it clear this is not what it wants. It adds poor content, which in turn attracts more poor content. We have millions of questions and answers, and it only needs a small percentage of those to be bad for it to be fairly noticeable and have a negative impact.
- **Stack Exchange** company should "be nice" and recognise that those arguing over the poor and lazy questions, and those who answer them, have to heart the very interest and goals Stack Exchange declares it has.

Some return points on what I've seen debated so far:

1. Site rules cannot only apply to those who have read and understood them! This would be unfair, so even new users without knowledge should be expected to learn, or need to be issued any relevant penalties.
2. Being a new user is not an excuse to not fix a poor question once learned of that requirement. They are getting all the benefits of the site's resources, functionality, and people's time, and it is therefore only fair that they uphold the requirements that make the sites great in the first place which is providing them with the aforementioned goodies!
3. "Be Nice" is great, but should not mean "leeway to let the rules slip by". That includes bad question after question after... and nothing done about it.
4. This should be about "all users" being nice, and regardless entirely of any particular action taken. So rather than focussing on commenters being unkind, also see that *poor questions are unkind* to both people trying to help and quality of the sites.

**Most importantly:**

5. If question quality rules were perhaps a bit stricter, but definitely enforced much sooner so bad questions don't stand a chance, then there'd be much less of a problem with people not being nice, because there will be much less to not be nice about!

There are many ways to fix (5), but they're risky so the site won't take the risk in case it backfires.

If we could make a ton of bad questions not happen, and more go away quickly, it would greatly reduce bad comments and people not being nice, because laziness and no care for the site's quality is where a lot of "not being nice" comes from.

Comment: I find this idea that posting poor questions represents rudeness equivalent to telling someone off is quite frankly absurd. Yes, a bad question is not good for the site, but it is not in the same ballpark as a direct, personal attack. Second, it should be noted that the Meta post on comments [*never* mentions new users or established uers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311737/164572). The statements outlined there are about *all* comments, not just comments from non-new users.

Comment: @NicolBolas compared to someone telling someone off, of course that's more rude. But that's such a small percentage of what this whole be nice in comments offensive has been about. It's about snarkiness, sarcasm, neither of which are "telling someone off": and often are instead providing valuable criticism only in a way that is more blunt than is needed. "Telling someone off" already gets routinely flagged and dealt with.It's the snarkiness and sarcasm that hasn't been handled properly.

Answer (score 7):

Based on my observations, it is more like the opposite: SE is not giving enough attention to the “be nice”-policy.

It has been [almost six years](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/20/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) while I observe them trying and I've seen about handful their attempts but things only seem to get worse (not much worse mind you but still). [Quoting self](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281807/165773),

> how come that after years of plugging users' mouths and twisting their arms with *summers of love* and *hunting the snark*, the second-highest-voted question at MSO is [Why is Stack Overflow so **negative** of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601)

Frankly these repetitive fruitless crusades for nicety start more and more looking like smokescreen serving sole purpose to pretend that they care. I would very much appreciate if they put more effort and achieve real improvements at last.

From this perspective your idea of giving users effective tools to stop the flood of poorly researched questions<sup>[*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370015/839601)</sup> looks worth pursuing. The sad thing is, it seems to be quite effort consuming and difficult to get right, and because of that I am really unsure if SE considers matters of keeping the network nice serious enough to invest effort into stuff like that.

Comment: The question here is about the ***present***, not past. True, in the past they gave it zero attention, and they admitted that was a mistake. So saying "it was bad in the past" is just unfair and not really related to the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard as of now I haven't seen any substantial differences with how it was in the past, that makes me feel that this essentially repeats what was before. As for your note about attention, I don't get it, per my experience these matters have always been getting a lot of it, this time it doesn't look much different

Comment: You said "SE is not giving enough attention". That is true, in the past. Now they give lots of attention, which has yet to bring actual changes. We're still not there though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it seems to be getting about the same attention now as I've seen in the past and based on that past efforts didn't work I assume it is not enough, they need to try harder if they want to really improve things

Comment: You mean "Summer of love" etc? I don't recall it being accompanied with blog posts and actual change in code of conduct. (That will lead to punishments for those not obeying it, being more than just recommendation.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah they didn't try this yet. They tried a lot of other things in prior "iterations" and all these things looked different and none of it worked. And based on that I don't expect that this new invention will work where all of their prior attempts failed (I would be more than happy to be proven wrong this time, I guess we'll have to just wait and see)

Comment: Well, this time they have external eyes looking their every step,  and they can't just let it evaporate like before. **Something** will happen, good or bad we can't know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't understand what you mean talking about external eyes, sorry. As I wrote to me it doesn't look much different from their past attempts

Comment: Google "april wensel stack overflow" (without quotes) to see what I mean. That's what sparked this whole thing, and since then I suspect many others with high influence started to follow this "situation" on twitter, so it is not limited to one person anymore. That's what I meant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see, thanks for explaining. I am aware of that "april wensel" thing and I don't expect it to make any meaningful difference. Guess we'll have to just wait and see

Comment: Put a reminder to visit those comments in one year, we'll see. :)

Comment: in one year we will likely have yet another battle-for-niceness and I will be again accused of referring to the past in discussions about ***present*** @ShadowWizard :)

Comment: nah.... the gap is bigger. And pretty sure the project currently rolling will still be on the roll, somehow.

Answer (score 7):

I'm fine with being polite to everyone.  But if I went to the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/) because I had a stomach ache, I'd be politely told to see my personal physician first.  Important facilities and important people have polite but firm gatekeepers.  Could we not have something similar here?

Stack Exchange has a reputation system that rewards contributions to the site and offers privileges to those who contribute more.  One of those privileges could be that high rep users could opt not to be confronted by unfiltered questions.  For example, if a question has fewer than N upvotes, then it is invisible.  Each high rep user gets to choose her own value of N.  There are other cutoff possibilities, such as the cumulative score or the number of downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

There's a few practical considerations here.

There's almost certainly a PR angle. I'm sure folks in SO Corp are hearing a lot of voices we don't about how SO feels hostile towards new users - not just the really loud ones we notice. In a sense we're in a bit of a blind spot. We have a clear idea of what we want, just not always the perception someone who hasn't had 6 months or a year or 8 years on the site has.

Be nice has also been a bit of a cornerstone of interactions on SE from the start - the only difference I suppose is that every so often folks go "We could be doing better on this front"

As an early, but not so early user of the network - well, I've had the benefit of growing with the rules. Some of my early posts probably wouldn't pass muster these days.

And well, a lot of old users are eventually going to leave. Some get bored, find other things and so on. Sites are going to rely on a core of new users.

I used to be part of a small community that was a little on the fringe, and sometimes attracted even fringier folk. It was in a interesting situation where it needed some quality control to keep out the crazy folk to keep the slightly saner and interesting ones. At some point, the admin went on a bit of a power trip. He ended up chasing off one of the mods, and her friend. There was no real new blood. Eventually people left, or even died. Last I checked, there were two idling people left in their chatroom, their website was gone...

So its a balance. Quality is important. On the other hand, some of the newbies you chase off might end up being folks who're engaged and willing to contribute in future. On the other, we're here for the challenging posts and the imaginary internet points.

There's always going to be *some* folks who're primarily going to see SE as a place to ask questions, and not really make an effort. There's going to be the folks who dump misformatted code, or use it as ELIF as a service. Its ok. We can still be civil, and just close, DV or delete these things. On the other hand, its not really healthy to see it as a "us vs them". To see new users as vandals - rather than, well, people who haven't had the same experiences you've had is divisive

In a sense, the be nice policy, and helping onboard new users is a good strategy for the *long term* health of a site. Helping them get up to speed and maintaining post quality isn't orthogonal to it.

Comment: "*Helping them get up to speed and maintaining post quality isn't orthogonal to it.*" I don't come here to help someone get up to speed on this site. That's not why I was attracted to SO. I came here because I enjoy answering interesting questions, and that's it. Why should I invest time in helping people do what they've been told to do? Also, new users are not vandals; *vandals* are vandals. That is, users who post crap questions are vandals, whether they're new or old.

Comment: Some evidence for your claim about the public image of SO: https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: @Chair That's not evidence.  It's a rant by someone who doesn't get SO's purpose.

Comment: @fbueckert It is a rant by someone about the high entry barriers. Yes, they don't understand the purpose and the measures taken to ensure the proper running. I don't agree with the claims at all, and it seems like a lot of fallacious reasoning What they see as 'people running away' is actually just help vampires who misuse SO for their own quick needs. But it shows that people outside aren't happy with SO, which is evidence. They paint a nasty, false picture of SO as rude and elitist. Note the number of upvotes/claps on the post: it's very popular. The comments there empathize with the author.

Comment: @Chair People not understanding SE are not worth considering.  Yes, they are not happy, but they are the kind of people we *can't* make happy.  So trying does nothing but frustrate us all.  And when someone tries that hard to misunderstand SE, I feel giving them attention does nothing but validate their opinion.

Comment: I am going to disagree somewhat. I do agree there's folks who fundamentally disagree with how we run SE without understanding what makes things work. There's also people with agendas and audiences who target SE cause it's at least culturally significant. Even they can be right at times. We do need to balance between the loud external voices telling us what to do and the risk of basically never listening to anyone but insiders.

Comment: @fbueckert it's worth noting the number of people who agreed with that post. If so many of the don't want to listen to us when we tell them how SO works (and no, you can't expect them to inherently _know_ that), then we're probably doing something wrong. We can't ignore outside opinions completely just because they're voiced by people who violate our ideology.

Comment: The tl;dr of the link posted by @Chair: ["That city's littering laws are too strict. I'd leave, but for some reason every other city is covered in garbage."](https://twitter.com/drob/status/618120713522802688)

Comment: Funny. Singapore has strict laws on littering. Signs about fines, community service. Signs telling people not to litter are good. Summarily shooting litterbugs in the knee... less so.

Comment: My problem with the article is that it called all our rule-enforcers 'trolls', which is ironic. It reflects the author's closed mindset and lack of understanding (and lack of attempts to understand). But that's what potentially good new users may be reading, and they won't know how trashy the article is. By providing _less_ incentive for people to write such rants, we can ensure a steady, productive growth of the high-quality population of the SE user base. Our inability to even notice this epitomizes the already-perfect-don't-tell-me-what-to-do state that outsiders see as the bane of SO.

Comment: @Chair If someone wants us to change, ranting about it elsewhere and cherry picking examples to make their point smacks of dishonesty.  Acknowledging them just validates their argument.  If users want to change SE, they have to work *with* us, not rant into the void with strawman and misunderstandings.

Comment: @fbueckert We all agree that the author of that post is crazy, so you need to drop that point. _Outsiders do not know that it is a bad post._ I'm acknowledging that the author's point exists and is popular. That isn't supporting him in any way. We need to change SE, but not in the manner suggested by John Slegers. We need to change things to stop the creation of specimens like him. Saying "People not understanding SE are not worth considering" is just burying your head in the sand. He's upset and completely wrong, but it may very well be so because we rubbed him the wrong way to begin with.

Comment: @Chair We can't drop that point because it's *central* to the entire problem.  Anyone who agrees with his article is irrelevant to SE.  If they want to work with us, then *work with us*.  Clicking an anonymous agree button on it does absolutely nothing.  I actually had a discussion with John right after that welcoming blog.  He dug in and refused to acknowledge anything that didn't agree with him.  So, no, it's not burying my head in the sand.  It's actively discounting his entire stance.

Comment: @fbueckert We _can_ drop the point because almost everyone _agrees_ he's nuts. He's wrong, but there's a reason why he holds such a misguided (IMO) opinion. His stance is wrong, he hurls unjustified insults and even misuses his most prolific insult: troll, but he still represents an opinion that's out there. (On a side note, you should look at his other articles. All are a similar vein). I don't see a valid objection to the claim that John Slegers is telling a lot of people a lot of bad things about us. If follows clearly that we don't want such characters to exist.

Comment: I was actually considering a series of events revolving around twitter. Funny thing was what I was thinking was "ugh, this might cause people to circle the wagons, which is exactly the opposite of what a healthy community needs to do" which is what a few folk seem to be advocating

Answer (score 5):

My experience as a user and a moderator seems to have been somewhat different from yours. This all resonates with me as crucial work.

I have seen negative attitudes, ranging from put-downs with questionably plausible deniability, to snark, to rudeness, to blatant hostility, directed at all kinds of people, all the way from brand new people, to people who've found their footing, to sites' longest-active members. It's not just new users that bring out the worst in us.

Sure, there are certainly issues with low-effort, poorly researched questions (and answers!), whatever the specific variety. I truly do believe that efforts related to Be Nice can help here, whether it's coaxing a new user into the community, or providing feedback in a way a post author can comfortably hear and act on, or simply avoiding escalating ugly situations. And I do also believe that there are other promising ways to address, as evidenced by all the meta discussion across the history of the network. I'm happy to see effort spent on those.

But there are *also* issues with being nice, being friendly, being kind. These issues are also well worth addressing. And honestly, I think we've all dropped the ball on this a bit, including me. I've posted and discussed my fair share of bug reports and feature requests, all those ideas for how to improve various technical and UI aspects of the site, and I've seen plenty of more of that from others in chat and on meta. I've seen and participated in huge discussions of the minutiae of what is and isn't on-topic, of the best thing to do about one single post. But there's been relatively little simply about how to better live up to what's always been a core value: being good to each other.

This work is hard, but it also really, truly matters. It affects who decides to go beyond their initial efforts to joining the community; it affects who sticks with it long-term and who leaves. The more issues we sweep under the rug, the more good people we lose. The more welcoming and fulfilling of an environment we build, the better off we all are.

Comment: "*I truly do believe that efforts related to Be Nice can help here*" How will being nice help reduce the amount of low-effort trash that gets posted? The thing you have to remember is that there is an endless sea of people who just want help out there. Whether we're nice or rude, that tide will crash against these shores. We're not going to magically transform them into reasonable posters who can think and debug for themselves. That's not to say that being nice is wrong; it's just not going to solve *that* problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas I said it could help, not magically fix everything. It increases the likelihood of things being salvaged, and it also decreases the likelihood of things devolving into drama that consumes far too much of people's time. Increasing the number of new users who join the community also increases the amount of community moderation time available. And of course, the point of my answer is that this *is* overall an important effort to pursue, not that low-quality questions *aren't* an issue.

Comment: "*It increases the likelihood of things being salvaged*" Taking the time to salvage something takes time away from questions that don't need to be salvaged. Why should we spend time on crap when we could spend time on good questions? "*it also decreases the likelihood of things devolving into drama that consumes far too much of people's time*" So does downvoting, voting to close, and moving on without comment. But some people will consider that rude.

Comment: Questions aren't divided into crap and obviously fine questions, and new users are not divided into lost causes and immediately positive contributors. Yes, there are of course cases where it's not worth bothering. (Note also that I mentioned "avoiding escalating ugly situations". Given a choice between not-nice comments, and just silently voting to close, the latter is preferable.) But there are also plenty of cases where we're not as nice as we could be and it *would* make a positive difference to the community. And again: this isn't just about crap. It's about being kind *in general*.

Comment: If you don't enjoy working with a user to improve their question, don't do it. It's supposed to be fun, not a job. Other people who do enjoy teaching can work on that or those questions can fade into the background or they can be handled by people on review queues or silent close votes.   I would like to see a discussion of whether aspects of the implementation of of gamification are creating incentives for not niceness.

Comment: @Elin that's the thing, we don't enjoy it, but it is shoved in our faces, since there's no way to show only those questions that we enjoy. It takes effort to: read the titles, read the body of the question, evaluating the question and deciding what to do. Remember that only when you evaluate the question you would notice that is crap, and there's the sunken cost of having already done the effort on the previous steps. It's irrational ask the people that already spend their time and energy to not do get frustrated because they did something they didn't enjoy.

Comment: Does feeling frustrated make you feel good, if not, just skim and walk on by rather than invest more time in it. Does being rude actually make you feel good?  I really doubt that venting adds to your enjoyment of   life or  using the site.

Comment: @Elin: Venting is called "venting" for a reason; it allows a release of pressure and tension. It's not about adding enjoyment; it's about releasing anger and frustration at having one's time wasted. Even "skimming" takes time, and having that time wasted is helpful to nobody.

Comment: It's indeed sometimes helpful to vent, but who we vent to matters. If it's someone who's interested in listening to and supporting us, that's great. If we're expressing your frustration to the object of that frustration to make ourselves feel better, we're putting our needs and wishes above theirs. We don't do that here. The policy isn't Be Nice, Unless It Feels Good Not To Be.

Comment: If being on SE makes you feel so angry, I'd suggest taking a break for a bit. Or find something on SE besides reading new questions.  It's a hobby. It should feel good or at least satisfying.   Also, venting should be done with people you know and trust, it is not the same as yelling at the person making you angry. 
 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/evolution-the-self/201404/6-virtues-and-6-vices-venting

Answer (score 5):

> Why is SE giving so much attention to the “be nice”-policy?

I'd say that a significant number of people believe that the "be nice" policy threatens to lower quality by being soft on bad question askers, and by making it harder for moderators/answerers to enforce "the rules". Enforcing rules and maintaining quality does not have to be mutually exclusive with "being nice".

I really like reading comments, and don't consider them to be "second class citizens" at all. Having read all the comments on this page, I've noticed a recurrent stance: that being nice isn't going to be this magic bullet which solves all our problems, and that we should focus our effort elsewhere on a more promising course of action. The flaw in that line of reasoning is that being nice is the end product of some process that requires a constant expenditure of energy and consumes an unreasonable amount of the limited resources at our disposal.

Ahem, being good natured does not sink energy, it sources it! A good deed is its own reward; perhaps a bit corny, but if examined and embraced is ultimately very powerful.

This backlash I've noticed may in part be due to phrase "be nice" itself. The word nice doesn't bother me, but sometimes it has the connotation of being soft or lacking in resolve. "Nice" has an unappealing tone when use in the phrase "nice guys finish last". I don't recall hearing anything uncomplimentary about the term "civility". I think that having a "be civil" policy would be more neutral and palatable than "be nice", given the prevalence of self-centered haughty attitudes today. To clarify, I'm not suggesting that this attitude characterizes us (the SE community), but that it affects us.

Another school of resistance that gets support is that we are at war with an endless sea of solution mongers who will ultimately overwhelm us with their growing ranks of henchmen, and that we must deliver some massive blow to their nerve center that sends them scurrying once and for all. This makes it easy to dismiss "being nice" as an inadequate defense given the scope of the threat. Let's not forget the story (fable, was it?) of the tortoise and the hare. Slow and steady wins the race. Kill 'em with kindness. If you can't beat 'em, join 'em. Niceness might be a lightweight compared to this behemoth we face, but why not just dust off what we already have lying around and steadily build at a sustainable rate. Keep brainstorming one morsel at a time. And don't be surprised at who shows up for dinner.

After reading all of the answers, I'm a bit disappointed at the unity. It seems like all the answers came from the same team. One might conclude that we're all in agreement. Why haven't any of the commenters who have expressed opposing viewpoints tried to reach a larger audience on the stage that answers provide?

P.S.  I find it interesting that the lowest rated answer here got the highest volume of comments. I wonder if motivation behind the production of these comments is coming from the same place that is "giving so much attention to the “be nice”-policy".

Comment: Welcome to this thread! Yes, among other things it became a place to vent frustrations. But, I hope you agree, this is one of the best places to air those. Personally, I have been gained a lot of perspective from this discussion. Most of it is, ach, so familiar from math meta. Some of it is new to me. I don't regret posting, but now I would use a different comparison.

Comment: "Yes, among other things it became a place to vent frustrations." What is the "it" you're referring to?

Comment: I referred to "this thread" in Meta.SE,

Comment: Thanks, being brand new to Meta, things like "welcome" , "discussion", and "vent" had me a bit off balance (taking the tour took the edge off my confusion).  As far as your use of a different comparison, I like the one you used. It seems to me that it really got the conversational ball rolling.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, I think that having frustrated mods and overlords doesn't help anyone. After reading your question I've found it is mostly a fault in communication and information.

Following your analogy, if a museum has a big sign telling visitors: "Any art is acceptable here! You are welcome!" it is logical every kid with a spraycan will try to come and submit their art. But a museum isn't a gallery, so among the Mona Lisas, the Last Suppers and bunch, there isn't space for new artists to show their work, so they come with the basic idea that the whole space is their playground. And then you have the results you mentioned.

What I think is necessary here to reconsider is 4 points of view that are independant, coherent and non-exclusive to each other:

- **The Museum's point of view**: A museum works as long as it has something new to show. To have that it must constantly invite new people to the museum to create and to stay relevant.
- **The Security Guard's point of view**: Security guards are employed by the museum to keep visitors happy, in order to keep them there and have revenue. As long as no one is actually making irreversible damage, the guards don't care.
- **The Curator's point of view**: Curators are there to educate and guide new and old users. Curators can give old users some depth and to interest new users in new things.
- **The User's point of view**: Users want to spend their time the best way possible, they want to contribute and be part of something bigger than themselves.

---

And each and every point of view is valid and it is coherent. So where is the frustration coming from? Well the main problem is in sign - it doesn't hold much information. Sign is made by museum for the users without any communication between two and without any input from Curators and Guards. To distance myself from allegory, I will now try and explain real issues that generate such frustration without any contemplative allegory.

SE thrives on users, as long as there are users SE gets payed trough job offers and revenue. So main focus of SE is that it has constant income of new users. But having new users doesn't mean that those users will stay and be part of community. SE needs a way to keep them here - so SE doesn't sell knowledge it sells community. But it doesn't have where to put that community and doesn't have means how to animate them. So instead of placing "you have to be this tall to drive!" it says "...come! lets hang out! You will drive eventually!". So any new user that comes upon this website hears "SE is great way to fix your problems!" from payed webcomics, news articles...

---

So from the users' point of view "It must be some community that help people in need! That is awesome! Can't wait to grow so I can help other people!", where main point here is *grow*. But SE doesn't have kiddy pool, or a system where users can be redirected in their early stages of growth into question that can help them, but instead prompts them to ask a question. And normally if a new user ask a question it will use a "spraycan" approach since that user doesn't have the technical vocabulary or knowledge to formulate a question correctly and not to mention to follow all the SE rules. So coming from low-knowledge standpoint, "awesome community to grow in" becomes behemoth of cold shoulders and opinionated ...... But that isn't in fact the reality, it just seems like that to the new user, and SE needs them. If SE stops growing, it stops being relevant and therefore stops generating revenue.

---

From the non-diamond (ND) moderators' points of view, they are there to answer any questions they know answers to, and to keep SE clean and relevant. So when a user [new or old] encounters an ND mod, old users don't get hurt because they know it is business as usual. But new users didn't read any disclaimer about business and for someone that expects a hug and get a shrug it is unwelcoming, and only because new user expects "open arms warm community" it was advertised to him/her. Which in turn frustrates ND mod since there is sudden overflow with "hoodlums". ND then becomes more focused on self defence towards new user tantrums and therefore distancing themselves from other users.

---

From the diamond moderators point of view, they are there to moderate the website and make sure that everyone can find what they need. Filter out duplicates, handle flags, etc. They are caretakers/curators of this "museum", and old users see them as persons of credibility while new users see them as extension of oppression. In reality, user interaction isn't part of their job. Diamond moderators are there to guide users, not to handle new ones. So frustration of ND mods translates to diamond moderators and then they have opposing force of some of ND mods trying to be "as advertised". Which is, *pardon my french*, a clusterfuck.

---

From SE point of view, its job is to advertise and generate revenue to stay relevant. It has passed some of responsibility to ND and diamond moderators, and they don't care what happens in the bull pin as long as it works. I've sent an bunch of emails across several years and still to this date no answer - which is ok. They are busy governing the public appearance of website more than controlling it (from their point of view it is mods job).

## How can we fix frustration?

First, we need a new "mod" type; in museum analogy it would be PR. Someone who would say to the museum "Stop! Don't put that sign out there! If you want to invite kids to play, you first need a kindergarten!".

PR would then say to the ND mods, "If you see a kid going around, place them in the kindergarten. Any kid that doesn't fulfill these requirements needs to have a spray can and a free wall."

And to diamond moderators: "Don't let other users be snobs. If you see a kid, introduce him/her to other ND mods and let them point it to the right place, before that kid graduates to a Q&A mindset".

And to users: "Hello! Nice to meet you! You can find free spray cans and walls in the yard. If you have any questions, first ask the ND mod to point you to an already-asked question in a similar manner. Enjoy our community!!"

### But SE doesn't have anyone for community management.

So miscommunication is bound to happen. Expectancies of advertisement and of community don't hold up. And you have bunch of new teenager hoodlums with spray cans spraying everywhere.

Please don't think that issues are in "Guards" or somewhere else. Each and everyone of you does splendidly their job, but there isn't any communication about plans of SE and the community. Keep strong.

Comment: Thanks for coming and sharing your thoughts. I think you are on to something. Meanwhile, I did realize that the real source of my frustration is the type 3s. In the museum analogy they are like those skilled drawers, sketching 3 minute portraits day-in day-out for a dollar. The problem is that they have occupied the first as well as the second floors of the museum, pushing art of permanent value further up, mostly hidden. The noobs are actually either clients to those sketchers.

Comment: (cont'd)  In my ideal museum there would be no sketching, and I don't really care whether the problem is fixed by booting those paintasters or their clients, for one group won't survive without the other.

Comment: Anyway, you bring up useful points. Surely, there has been miscommunication about the goals of the site, **in particular about those goals shifting.** A lot of us were attracted to the place we saw as one rewarding skill and expertise. We aren't van Goghs or Pollocks, but in the next tier. People proven to be good enough to make a living with our skills, looking for a niché. Disgruntled because we are basically being told "Thanks for filling the place with nice material, giving us a lot of street cred. But we nowadays concentrate on facilitating 3-minute-sketching."

Comment: Or, if you prefer a sport analogy. Baseball players hovering between  triple-A and major league won't be happy about a system where all the money is in little league coaching.

Comment: If there is no business future for a site that doesn't need to be ashamed of being slightly elitist, the SE could have the spine to come forward and spell it out.

Comment: But, I like the idea of having a kindergarten here. Actually we do! The chatrooms. They could serve in the role of helping out newbies with their repetitive questions. The newbies could spend time there and also search the main halls. In Jeff Atwood's ideal SE the newbie programmers should spend 98% of their time searching (leaving out quotation marks for I don't want to search for the exact quote now). So to attract new users, the effort should be directed to making it easier to find the relevant already existing answers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen please don't go for sport analogies. I just skipped that comment whatsoever. I'm terrible at sports and often don't watch them... and I am not in US so ...baseball? I heard of it only from the movies ("if you build it they will come...") sutff. But lets continue...

Comment: If i understood analogy of first comment right. You are referencing expert answers to the beginner questions so noobs come to seek out those questions (Painting master and 3 minute sketches part) where real and hard questions are hidden due to the shear number of trivial issues. Honestly i can't agree with you more. I did answer a question on SE about this, tacking the main issues - i can link the question if you want it. But i do hope you understand that if we boot those types of questions, community will never get any fresh blood (since most of experts did start as noobs).

Comment: If we don't get new blood, in half of an century SO(and SE) would be limited by experts members that are still alive, with some educated users that follow rules that are century old. We must not forget that Tesla, Edison, Zuck and many others who were so different that they changed the way of thought without any formal education. No matter what our desires are, if we don't have counter pull progress is stale and self directed - therefore limited. So we need those customers since 1 in 1000 will remain and add some awesome shit to this community - which still remains 999 of spray cans.

Comment: And to get that big all shiny diamond from dirt,gravel and coal - we need dirt,gravel and coal and we need to apply a lot of pressure so that diamond is born. * "Thanks for filling the place with nice material, giving us a lot of street cred. But we nowadays concentrate on facilitating 3-minute-sketching."* and this is where SO(SE) fucked up in my opinion. It set the tier high, but then realised it wasn't self sustainable for such massive product ... and shifted the direction without anyone noticing. Shift in direction is natural and ok, but if you going to do any action ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1354/discussion-between-danilo-and-jyrki-lahtonen).

Comment: Who are **"Non-Diamond [ND] mods"**? Are there mods who don't have a diamond symbol next their username?

Comment: that are guys/gals who edit /flag /vote and spend their time basically working as an moderators without any gratification of the server. In SE mods are really basically administrators and , anyone who votes/edits/flags is an moderators.

Comment: “*are guys/gals who edit /flag /vote and spend their time basically working as an moderators*” In other words ordinary users who volunteer their free time to do a little housekeeping. P.S When a second user posts a comment, you need to use the @ followed by the username to notify them that you replied. When you are the author of the post, every time someone posts a comment beneath you'll get a notification. I didn't get any notification because the system can't tell if you want to communicate with @JyrkiLahtonen or myself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah ordinary user who volunteer their time to do little housekeeping. I found important to mention them too. Moderators do have most of the hard and repetitive jobs, but still it is important to mention that community is willing to contribute.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why SE is giving so much attention to the be nice policy, but I know why I want people to be nice to me and respectful toward each other on this site and elsewhere:

## Because it makes me feel good.

And incidentally, when I am happy because I have received the help that I need, I feel motivated to give in return and contribute to the community that I have become a part of.

In other words:

If you are generous and help me with my duplicate question that is lacking even the most basic research effort, I am grateful and the love that you gave me motivates me to give something in return. To you, or to the next person in my life that I meet.

> How can we best deal with our own (and each others) frustration?

Do you have children? I have a son. He is now 12 years old. He has driven me to insanity more times than there are stars in the universe. And yet I love him more than life itself.

I try not to drive him away so that I can peacefully follow my obsessions. I try not to suffocate his personality and stifle his development with rules that force him into my way of life. Instead, I accept his needs, his immaturity, his differences from me – the often painful *disturbance* that he is and try to love him as best I can.

Erik Erikson called this *generativity*.

I have grown and matured a lot since the birth of my son. I'm still a long way from the person I want to be, but generativity is a stance that I want to take on towards all the people that I encounter in my live. I try my best, but often I fail.

Comment: Respect? Respect for people taking a dump on my lawn?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen wait for when what got dumped hits the fan ...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Do you really feel that people asking homework questions compare to vandals defecating on your lawn?

Comment: Those of them who see the site as a free do-my-homework site are like that, yes. Several mathematicians refuse to participate in SE because the site has developed a reputation as a homework mill. It wasn't like that early on. But, by being "accommodating", we lost control. Then the sheer mass of such questions, askers and answerers drowns everything else.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was the highest rep user on two SE sites for many years before I left. I got tired of answering the same questions and dealing with the same "noobs" again and again. So I turned to other things. You don't have to make SE your purpose in life. You are free to move on. Trying to prevent people from coming here asking homework questions is like trying to prevent teenagers from sitting on the benches at the playground in the evening. You could dismantle the benches and force the mothers to sit on the floor in the daytime. But you could remember that you were a teen once, too.

Comment: All, last night I was a bit drunk, and one thing said here hit a personal sore point. So I reacted somewhat strongly. Anyway, I think that newbies should be forced to lurk for a certain number of hours on a minimum number of threads before allowed to post. Together with a *no rep for answering dupes* policy, this would alleviate the problems considerably.

Answer (score -2):

## Hide answers from bad questions

If bad questions still get answers, there is little incentive for questioners to write better ones.

To be more specific the idea is that in questions that are likely low quality(new user/low reputation user) the answers are automatically hidden and only shown if they are determined to be good questions(upvotes?/reviewed?)

Comment: This seems like a potentially interesting idea, but I'm not really sure of all the details, and it seems like it would do a lot better if posted as a separate feature request in its own right with a lot of the ins and outs worked out already.

Comment: This idea gained some support in Math meta. However, a type 2 user only needs to see an answer for a few seconds to copy it. So this needs an alert diamond bearer. May be SO has enough of those? At Math.SE we don't. We have timezone gaps between moderators and not enough people to begin with. Deletion of answers may affect type 3 users, but not all our moderators are sold on the need of such measures :-(

Comment: What is a bad question in this context?

Answer (score -9):

I think you're making a common mistake that even art museum curators make, from time to time: *forgetting why we're here*.

Stack Exchange sites aren't here for us to have a nice pretty museum that has a lot of things we like in it.  They're here for the *users*, those folks who come and ask questions.  And while some of "us" do ask questions, for the most part the "established SE users" are the answerers, not the askers.  The way we get new questions is by getting *new users*.

Imagine a museum curator whose taste is a bit behind the times, and is making a nice museum that *they* like, and insulting the tastes of the "new" people who don't like their exhibits; soon enough the number of new visitors drops to the point the museum closes.

We need a site that fits what the potential new users need.  It needs to be welcoming.  It needs to cater to their needs, be that by finding ways to help them ask better questions, or adapting to what questions they want to ask.

This doesn't mean we abandon all hopes of quality, nor does it mean we don't protect our nice exhibits.  What it means, though, is that our *attitude* has to be positive.  We have to think "how do we get these new users to stay here and contribute useful information" rather than "how do we get rid of these annoying new users".  How, in fact, do we change StackExchange for the better, to suit the changing needs of its customer/user base?

Comment: The site you're describing is not why I come here. I come here to provide answers to good questions. If catering to the needs of new users turns this site into a place that isn't about answering good questions, then the site has lost its way. We aren't here to be what any user needs; we're here to provide a useful resource. We don't help people. We help the Internet by creating useful information. We should not forget this.

Comment: The site you're describing, unfortunately, is one that won't create useful information for very long.  "Useful" to whom?  To users, presumably, by definition... and those users are the ones we need to consider.  I'm not suggesting abandon quality or anything else: what I'm saying is think of the users first and foremost, as our customers, and being nice is a major element in that.

Comment: "*The site you're describing, unfortunately, is one that won't create useful information for very long.*" It's managed to do so for nearly 10 years now. "*I'm not suggesting abandon quality or anything else*" The rules that new users chaffe against are the rules that preserve our quality. So yes, if we want more new users, we *have to* abandon our quality standards.

Comment: @Joe If gathering new users are more important than maintaining quality, then we're no better than the forums SE was created to replace.

Comment: @fbueckert I do not suggest we abandon maintaining quality.  Where is all of this coming from?  I say that we must pay attention to our new users, instead of simply saying "they don't like what we're doing so f*** them", and we must be nice to them instead of telling them off.  We can get a site that has questions that help people without being jerks to people, and we *need* to pay attention to the fact that we can easily get trapped in the "this is how I like it so get off my lawn".

Comment: @Joe We do pay attention to them.  But they need to adapt to the community they're entering.  We can certainly be more welcoming.  But all too often, new users see enforcing quality as rude, or unwelcoming.  That's the point Nicol and I are making.  Enforcing quality is very often the very problem new users have, and we can't make those users happy while doing so.  If making them happy is the goal, the logical conclusion is we do so at the expense of quality.

Comment: You can enforce quality without being rude...

Comment: I'm not saying we leave snarky comments.  Say we leave no comments.  We just downvote and close an off-topic question.  And when new users see that enforcement *as* rude?

Comment: @fbueckert That's certainly being rude.  You're just slamming the door in their face.  Being nice means being welcoming.  Helping people find ways to join the community.  How do you expect people to end up being useful contributors to the community if you don't help them get there?

Comment: I'm not going to say that closing and downvoting isn't sometimes the right answer; it's *often* the right answer.  And some users clearly don't want to be useful members of the community.  But it takes so little time to say something at least vaguely nice to someone...  "Hi, welcome to the site.  Your question isn't specific enough for our quality standards; can you take a look at [ask] and the [help] and see if you can improve it?  Feel free to ask here if you are unsure. Thanks."

Comment: That can be a canned response for quite a lot of the bad quality questions, and still provides a bit of dialog. It's polite, it allows them a way to get into a conversation about improving if they want to, shows them where to find help.

Comment: @Joe And I'm saying **it's not rude**.  It's literally the purpose of SE, to curate and maintain a high quality repository of knowledge.  In your quest to welcome more users, you'd throw our quality standards out the window.

Comment: Ask yourself: is this what I'd do if a neighbor or a person at work asked the same question?  I suspect you wouldn't simply shut the door in their face, even if they irritated you, right?

Comment: @Joe: "*That's certainly being rude.*" And removing the ability of us to remove bad questions would destroy the quality of the site. "*is this what I'd do if a neighbor or a person at work asked the same question?*" But we're not at work, nor are we in a neighbor's house. Your analogy is therefore irrelevant. We are on Stack Overflow, and the expectations for user behavior and question quality are set.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what people think is wrong with the sample comment Joe posted. I mean, I'd maybe be more specific, add something after the phrase "our quality standards", but . . . I don't know. I don't see how it could be interpreted as rude, and it gets the point across well enough.

Comment: @HDE226868: Nothing is wrong with it, and nobody is arguing against people saying that. Can you explain why downvoting and close voting should be seen as rude?

Comment: @NicolBolas So what's wrong with just using it? My understanding is that all that these discussions have been about is using more comments like that and fewer comments with snark. But people are resisting that sort of recommendation, and I'm trying to understand why. I don't think that downvoting and close voting are rude - they're *essential*.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's rude to *simply* downvote and close, without anything else, for the same reason ignoring a person asking you in person is.  This is one of those, "because it's the internet people forget about basic civility" things, to me.  If you wouldn't do it in person, don't do it online.

Comment: @HDE226868: Because 1) we don't necessarily trust our community moderator's standards of what is and is not "rude", 2) we certainly don't trust some AI's standards of what is and is not "rude", 3) at the end of the day, if sanctions are to be laid down for it, it is not the one-and-one question askers who will suffer for it. It's us. It's not the sentiment of "stop being rude" that's the problem; it's the *fervency* that SO advocates for it that is disconcerting.

Comment: @Joe No, it **absolutely** is not.  There are several orders of magnitude more new users than there are curators.  What you are proposing does not scale in any sense.  New users have the same resources as anybody else, the very ones you linked to.  If they don't have the, "civility" to read that, why are they entitled to more from us?

Comment: @Joe: "*It's rude to simply downvote and close, without anything else, for the same reason ignoring a person asking you in person is.*" [Welcome to the dichotomy between quality and kindness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness). If you force users to have to comment in order to downvote or close vote, then there will be fewer down/clode votes and/or more snarky comments. You reduce the ability of us to moderate the site. Thus reducing quality.

Comment: Quality is reduced because you don't get new users who know how to post good quality questions, if you don't comment and help them improve.  If you don't have time to add a (canned) comment, just ... don't do anything.  This scales because there's *lots of other users, too*, and you don't have to personally moderate the entire site...

Comment: @Joe I think you need to read [Opimizing for Pearls, not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: @Joe: If we don't moderate the site, who will? How will quality be maintained if nobody stops bad quality questions from proliferating? How will quality be maintained if nobody is downvoting content that shouldn't be looked at? The problem with those "lots of other users" is that ***they do not care about the quality of the site!*** They, like you, care more about people's feelings than the integrity of the system. They see SO as a help desk. We need less of that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think you need to stop saying "we" and start saying "I". As [Rand put it a couple days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311745/274942), anyone who isn't keen about this doesn't have to comment. There are other people who will do it. You don't speak for everyone on SO, and you don't speak for everyone on the network. And neither do I.

Comment: @HDE226868: That has nothing to do with what I said. I'm talking about making comments that, *to us* appear to be within the "be nice" policy, but are still moderated, through no fault of our own.

Comment: @NicolBolas If all of the other users have a different opinion on how to run the site than you... is there any chance they might have the *right* idea?  Or at least a *relevant* idea?  Just a thought.

Comment: @Joe Except they *don't* all have different opinions.  I, for one, agree with him.  The masses all agreeing doesn't automatically mean they're right, either; if that were true, we would've abolished downvoting a long time ago, because we get that feature request on a regular basis.  And if you want to appeal to the masses, well, just look at your net score. More disagree than agree.  Is there any chance *you* might have the wrong idea?

Comment: @Joe: "*If all of the other users have a different opinion on how to run the site than you...*" A lot of people have lots of bad ideas all the time. That's why we have rules in place to protect the system from their bad ideas. The tyranny of the majority is still a *tyranny*; the best defense against that is a well-defined set of principles that keeps us from degenerating into being ruled by a mob.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I'm not excessively worried about my museum getting out of touch. You see, math has a longer half-llife than the latest programming fads. It seems to me that the differences of opinion are about priorities. I entertain the position that over 99 per cent of the questions a freshman newbie can ask have already been answered on our site, possibly in an altered form that is a bit harder to find. So I would put the scarce resources towards enhancing the organization and searchability of the site and educating new users about those tools.

Comment: So facilitating repeats of old questions makes things worse, and a "summer of love" WITHOUT accompanying educational campaign may do just that.

Comment: From a user perspective, SE exists purely so people can outsource their thinking.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas "We don't help people. We help the Internet by creating useful information." The Internet has no value or purpose unless it gets USED by people. It is a THING; people built it, and for only one reason...  human use. I hope that I'm taking your comment out of context, because if that is literally what you are saying and how you feel, that means that others must surely share your ideology. If this is the destiny of what values become for lives to be lived, I am deeply saddened by what  future lives must endure. Nobody on their death bed wishes they had spent more time at the office.

Comment: "Prettiness" for the art museum is analogous to **utility** of questions for Stack Exchange sites. The users of Stack Exchange are, for the most part, **not** the people who ask (nor answer) questions; they are the people who *find a Stack Exchange page in search results*. Our curators have the advantage of knowing what "works" are currently *de rigeur* - because there is a Views counter on every Q&A page.

Comment: "We have to think "how do we get these new users to stay here and contribute useful information"" Most people are *not (yet) capable* of contributing useful information - and I am thinking here of **the questions**, not the answers. Questions are *typically at least as hard* to ask well as they are to answer - and for various reasons (that become truly absurd once one takes a properly distanced, outside view), we expect people *pre-selected to have the least* domain knowledge to fill this crucial role.