# Possible to get some Stack Overflow Comment Evaluator 5000™ save points or signposts?

Tags: feature-request, stackoverflow-comment-evaluator

I received the invitation to participate in the [Comment Evaluator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312447) today.  In the body of the email, there was a mention of:

> How much time are you asking me to commit?
>
> We're asking for
> participants to invest 1 hour, split into however many sessions you
> want. Don’t plan to work longer than 20 minutes on this task at one
> sitting. If you want to do more than one hour total you are encouraged
> to do so! If you do less than one hour, we may not be able to use your
> data.

I went on my way, thinking that perhaps there would be a point at which the system would stop me, let me take a breather, let me know that I could save progress, etc. Alas, by the time I realized the depth to which I had been absorbed in the process, I was well over the recommended time for one session.

I understand that in life, there aren't always directions, and I don't mind self-pacing myself, but at a minimum it would have been nice to have something that indicated my progress was being saved, or a means to explicitly do so, in case of a browser crash, etc.

I realize it's kind of a "bare bones"-type application (on the surface), and I'm certainly not suggesting it should be all snazzy or overengineered, but having some indicators on the screen would have certainly made it a more intuitive experience for me.

(It probably goes without saying, but I'll mention it anyway: I also realize that this potential change would not benefit me, but would hopefully be helpful to future cohorts of the Evaluator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My feeling too, it's a bit disconcerting to have no indication of whether I'm "nearly there yet".

I'm impressed by your perseverance, I lasted way less than you. It got boring because after I don't know how many pages I'd only seen maybe TWO comments that were borderline "not nice" - and that was possibly because I was getting bored of clicking just 'ok' all the time.

That aside, I find it soul-destroying to be labelling lots of comments as 'OK' when - despite the fact that they are not 'nasty', they are patently noise or adding zero value to the discussion. Couldn't we have a category of "not nasty, but not worth keeping either"?

Answer (score 6):

I was expecting there to be some kind of timer for this, but in the end I figured out that it was just a never-ending flow of comment streams (and I often saw the same threads two or three times (and yes, I know this is intentional)).

Some people are better at speed-reading than others, so I'm sure there's a wide variation of reviews per person.

I'm guessing that there's quite a few people still stabbing at smileys and waiting in vain to be told to stop.

And I was promised bad language, but there was no bad language (only Regex and Angular).